# How should I control the brightness on my Ubuntu 14.04 system?

Tags: dell, brightness, intel

Brightness control button is changing brightness value in file `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`, but screen brightness is not changing.

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/ , you can try this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this app will work for you :) https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/trusty/brightness-controller/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

---

On your terminal:

```
> gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
Locate: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
Change to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Then again in your terminal:
> sudo update-grub
```

Reboot Computer. Now it should work ! 
Proven on my Packard Bell TS11HR Laptop !